# Error checking Density of Input in a Neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am building a NN on Google Colab but I can't quite get the data to the right shape.

I entered data and set the parameters.  The error is "expected dense_31_input to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (12,)"

How do I reshape the data to fit the parameters?

```
X = df[['DEP', 'YOB', 'PHON', 'DOUTL', 'DOUTHP', 'DMORT', 'DHVAL', 'DOUTM', `'DAINC','NKID','DOUTCC','SINC']]`
y = df.BAD

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=99)

import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-542b3e6e5d63> in <module>()
     20 
     21 # fit the keras model on the dataset
---> 22 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
     23 
     24 # evaluate the keras model

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    143                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    144                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 145                             str(data_shape))
    146     return data
    147 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_31_input to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (12,)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO!. The way I understand it, your features array that you feed to your model has a shape `(12, )`, but when you initialise the Dense layer you specify that the `input_dim` is supposed to be 8. Therefore, it gets understandably confused when it gets `(12, )` instead. Either remove additional features from your features set to make it `(8, )` or specify `input_dim=12`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it went right through.  Great explanation.